# Animating transform-origin in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

So I have a couple of CSS animations currently used in a hybrid app I made:

```
@keyframes spaceInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform-origin: 0% 50%;
    transform: scale(.2) translate(-20%, 0%);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform-origin: 0% 50%;
    transform: scale(1) translate(0%, 0%);
  }
}

@keyframes spaceOutRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    transform: scale(1) translate(0%, 0%);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    transform: scale(.2) translate(20%, 0%);
  }
}
```

I'm in the process of porting said app to React Native and I've hit a road block with this animation. As you can see it uses transform-origin which React Native doesn't provide.

Currently I have:

```
Animatable.initializeRegistryWithDefinitions({
  spaceInLeft: {
    from: {
      opacity: 0,
      transform: [
        {
          scale: 0.2,
          translateX: '-20%',
          translateY: '0%',
        },
      ],
    },

    to: {
      opacity: 1,
      transform: [
        {
          scale: 1,
          translateX: '0%',
          translateY: '0%',
        },
      ],
    },
  },

  position: {
    from: {
      transform: [
        {
          translateX: 0,
          translateY: '50%',
        },
      ],
    },

    to: {
      transform: [
        {
          translateX: 0,
          translateY: '50%',
        },
      ],
    },
  },
});
```

I was wondering if anyone could please shed some light on how exactly I implement this exact origin change in React Native?

If it helps it's meant to look something like these...

[Scroll to the On the Space section](https://www.minimamente.com/example/magic_animations/)

Comment: Unfortunately, transform-origin is not supported in react native. You used to be able to do it using a matrix math trick shown here https://commitocracy.com/implementing-foldview-in-react-native-e970011f98b8, but that doesn't seem to work anymore =(

Comment: @FunkSoulNinja Yeah I guessed that, if that's not working either I don't suppose you know if I can achieve the animation without manipulating the origin? Thanks for your reply anyway.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62286550/4026902 this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've just found a workaround. Instead of using any sort of origin I've simply transformed it along the X axis.

```
  spaceInLeft: {
    0: {
      opacity: 0,
      scale: 0.2,
      translateX: 0,
      translateY: 0,
    },

    0.5: {
      scale: 0.6,
      translateX: -100,
      translateY: 0,
    },

    1: {
      opacity: 1,
      scale: 1,
      translateX: 0,
      translateY: 0,
    },
  },
```

I also think I add a syntax error with declaring a transform.