# React Native Transform Origin

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, transform

how do I apply the `transform-origin` property to a style in react native?
I've tried in several ways, but I did not get an event

I tried:

```
transform: [{ rotate: ('90deg')},{origin: {x: 'top', y:'center'}} ]
```

Comment: Looks like transform origin is not supported yet https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1964 and  https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/transforms-transform-origin-support

Answer (score 26):

**React native doesn't have any transform origin property yet. maybe in the future**

***but with a trick we can achieve this***

you should try to use translateX or translateY trick.

the trick is to first move the center of the shape to the origin that you want to rotate.

for example I have a shape with these properties

```
width: 60
height: 60
```

to rotate it from top left origin I should do these

```
translateX: -30
translateY: -30
rotate: 45deg
translateX: 30
translateY: 30
```

***be careful after rotation is done you should translate it back to it's orginal position***

**Note: to put the center of a shape to it's left side you can move it by half of it's width**

in this example I want to rotate a shape 35 deg from left most origin

```
transform: [
            
            {   
                translateX: -1 * (widthOfShape / 2)

            }
            },
            
            {
                rotate: '35deg'
            },
            {   
                translateX: (widthOfShape / 2)

            },
        ]
```

Answer (score 13):

I made a lib to achieve `transform-origin`.  [react-native-anchor-point](https://github.com/sueLan/react-native-anchor-point).

> Provides a function like transform-origin in CSS, anchor point in iOS, pivot point in Android.

easy to use

```
import { withAnchorPoint } from 'react-native-anchor-point';

getTransform = () => {
    let transform = {
        transform: [{ perspective: 400 }, { rotateX: rotateValue }],
    };
    return withAnchorPoint(transform, { x: 0, y: 0.5 }, { width: CARD_WIDTH, height: CARD_HEIGHT });
};

<Animated.View style={[styles.blockBlue, this.getTransform()]} />
```

[image]

Comment: you're a life saver. this is exactly what I needed

Comment: any other examples of how to use this library besides the one on the repo? It's not too clear for different types of transform

Answer (score 1):

**It's now possible since react native 0.73**

- [link to the the doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/transforms#transform-origin)
- [Link to the playground](https://snack.expo.dev/@topkat/transformorigin)

This is how it's implemented:

```
<View
  style={[{
    transformOrigin: 'top',
    transform: [{rotate: '90deg'}],
  }]}
/>
```