# Rotate View from a specific point - React Native

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, math, react-native-reanimated

I'm trying to rotate a View from a starting point,

I'm tried to add prev translateX and add it again after rotating as describing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58444898/11848459)
but not works well :\ it's the same

[image: shot]

Code snippet

```
  const rotateAnimationStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      transform: [
        {translateX: -1 * (120 / 2)},
        // {translateY: 0},
        {rotateZ: `${rotateAnimationValuew.value}deg`},
        {translateX: 120 / 2},
        // {translateY: 0},
      ],
    };
  });


 const addAttachment = () => {
    isAnimated.value = withTiming(!isAnimated.value, {duration: 4000});
    rotateAnimationValuew.value = isAnimated.value
      ? withTiming(0, {
          duration: 1500,
          easing: Easing.linear,
        })
      : withTiming(90, {
          duration: 1500,
          easing: Easing.linear,
        });

    console.log(isAnimated.value);
  };





  <Animated.View
     style={[styles.attachmentsElements, rotateAnimationStyle]}>
       <View style={[styles.circle, {zIndex: 1}]}>
            <Text>close</Text>
       </View>
       <View style={styles.circle}>
            <Text>Camera</Text>
       </View>
       <View style={styles.circle}>
            <Text>video</Text>
       </View>
       <View style={styles.circle}>
            <Text>Contacts</Text>
       </View>
   </Animated.View>
```