# How scale up from the bottom of an view in react native?

Tags: css, react-native, react-native-animatable

I want to have an animation scale up with scaleY to fill up a view. The problem is that it starts from the center instead of the bottom. How can I change it so that animation starts from the bottom?

```
 const fillAnim = {
    0: {
        transform: [{ scaleY: 0 }]
    },
    0.25: {
        transform: [{ scaleY: 0 }]
    },
    0.5: {
        transform: [{ scaleY: 1 }]
    },
    0.75: {
        transform: [{ scaleY: 1 }]
    },
    1: {
        transform: [{ scaleY: 0 }]
    }
};
```

I am using react-native-animatable for this animation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Transform Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52561376/react-native-transform-origin)

Comment: No, I tried to use the translation trick but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
transform-origin: bottom;
```

should fix the issue.

Comment: transform-origin is not supported in react-native

Comment: same error, can you fixed?