# Left-align a scaled View/Text with react-native's Animated API

Tags: react-native, react-animated

I a trying to build a 'Material-UI-like' `TextInput` with a large label that shrinks down when the field is selected.

I am having issues with scaling the label. Applying a `transform: [{scale: ...}]` shrinks the `Text`, but does so around the center of the field. I am failing to keep the label left-aligned during the scaling process, as I'd need to dynamically be able to access the view's width to offset it, but I can't seem to be able to get it using normal means(i.e. `onLayout`, which does not seem to be triggered during the animation).

Here is an example demonstrating the issue:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, Animated } from 'react-native';

export const F = (): JSX.Element => {
  const scale = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0.0)).current;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const animation = Animated.timing(scale, {
      toValue: 1.0,
      duration: 1000,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    });

    animation.start();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          transform: [
            {
              scale: scale.interpolate({
                inputRange: [0, 1],
                outputRange: [1, 0.5],
              }),
            },
          ],
          backgroundColor: 'yellow',
        }}
        onLayout={(e) => console.log({ view: e.nativeEvent.layout })}>
        <Text onLayout={(e) => console.log({ text: e.nativeEvent.layout })}>
          Label
        </Text>
      </Animated.View>
      <TextInput style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue' }} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Example after the text has been scaled by half:

[image: Issue]

Note how the yellow view (`Text`) is no longer left aligned because of the scaling.

I've created a stack to explain what I am trying to accomplish:

https://snack.expo.dev/@bertrand-caron/trembling-beef-jerky

I'd like the `Label` View (yellow) to stay left align when scaled, instead of being shrunk centered inside the red view.

Comment: I think this is about transform-origin. Just set transform-origin the the left.But rn don't support transform-origin.There is a similar [issue link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52561376/react-native-transform-origin/58444898)

Answer (score 2):

I have two solution:

**1.** For this I have created a snack: https://snack.expo.dev/PFN07UigC .
Let me know if it fits. For left aligning I just used `justify-content:'flex-start'` to its container.

**2.** If you wish to calculate it you know the initial size with `onLayout` and you have the `scale` let us assume that `scale` you are using is `0.5` and the `onLayout` gave you `100` then the `margin-left` that you are wanted is `(width-(width*scale))/2` which is in our case `25`. But I don't see any need for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for having a look. I've edited my question (and added my own Snack) to better explain it. The problem is keeping the view left aligned after being shrunk. `onLayout` does not seem to update while the text is being resized.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you should make the `<Animated.Text/>` rather than `<Animated.View/>`. But it will also work.

If you don’t use `alignSelf: 'flex-start'` it will take the same space as the `Parent View`.

Here is my solution: https://snack.expo.dev/@fanish/textinput-animation

```
      <Animated.Text
        style={{
          ...textStyle,
          transform: [{ scale }],
          alignSelf: 'flex-start',
        }}>
        Label
      </Animated.Text>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your submission! I still want the left edge of the red rectangle to say on top of the left edge of the yellow one, which is not the case.

Comment: For that, you can use `translateX` with respect to `onLayout={({ nativeEvent: { layout: { width } } }) => { setPositionX(-width / 2) }}`

[https://snack.expo.dev/@fanish/textinput-animation](https://snack.expo.dev/@fanish/textinput-animation)